# sshfs - incorrect, old directory structure shown in remote volume, can't access data

Tags: sshfs

I sshfs'd into a remote server with standard syntax:

```
sshfs ubuntu@server.somewhere.com:/home/ubuntu/ ./myfolder -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/my-private-key.pem -o allow_other
```

Everything worked fine. The file structure there was

```
/all/data/workdata
```

Then, the remote server changed the file structure and reset the machine. The new structure is now

```
/all/new/data/workdata
```

I unmounted with

```
sudo umount -l myfolder
```

then remounted. Now I can't access anything. The "old" folder structure is retained for me, and when I am in /all/, `dir` still shows "data". If I try to cd there, I get "no such directory" (also if I try to cd into the invisible "new"). I've tried `-o cache_timeout=0 -o workaround=rename`. I can sshfs into other remote servers normally. What is going on? How can I get into the server?

Comment: How is `/home/ubuntu` (the folder you mount) on the server related to `/all/...`? You might want to add the output of `ls -alh /all` on the server side and the output of `ls -alh ./myfolder` on your local machine.

Comment: `/home/ubuntu` is where `/all/` is located after the file system of the server was changed. The `ls -alh /all` output from the local machine shows `all` in red text, with an arrow pointing to white, blinking `/data/workdata`. `ls -alh` from the sever shows `/all/` in blue text.

Comment: It still sounds a bit confusing for me how `/home/ubuntu` and `/all` folder are connected as these are completely different locations in the filesystem and you are trying to mount `/home/ubuntu` from the server. I think best would be you talk to the admin of the server to tackle your problems.

Comment: The *white, blinking* `all` folder indicates a dead symbolic link which needs to be updated. From the information you provided it still does not relate to the paths you mentioned in your question.

Comment: It turns out I just need to use `-o follow_symlinks`. Now everything is working as expected. Thanks for your help!